# SwiftUI Push View with NavigationLink from modal view

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I present a modal view with `fullScreenCover` by pressing "present my modal" button:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var presentMyModal = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presentMyModal) {
                    MyModalView()
            }
        Button(action: { presentMyModal = true },
               label: { Text("present my modal")})
    }
}
```

Then I want to push a new view with `NavigationLink` from this modal:

```
struct MyAlertView: View {

    @State var pushNavigationLinkedView = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("MyAlertView")
            .padding()
        Button(action: { pushNavigationLinkedView = true },
               label: { Text("push navigation linked view")})

        NavigationLink(destination: NavigationLinkedView(),
                       isActive: $pushNavigationLinkedView) {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `NavigationLinkedView` :

```
struct NavigationLinkedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("NavigationLinkedView")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

But nothing happens when I press "push navigation linked view" button.

So is it allowed by apple guideline to push a view with `NavigationLink` from a modal view ? If yes, what is the best way to do it ?

Tested on iOS15 and XCode 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it allowed by Apple guideline to push a view with `NavigationLink` from a modal view?

Yes. Just make sure you have a `NavigationView` at the base of `MyAlertView`. The modal sheet creates a new view hierarchy, and `NavigationLink` only works when there’s a `NavigationView` somewhere in the hierarchy above.